# Is it safe to download Git from Sourceforge.net?

Tags: git, github

So I'm new to programming and would like to learn Git using the command line and have been directed to the https://git-scm.com/downloads page. However I notice the download link points to Sourceforge.net which I have been told is not safe to download software from.

Is this something I should be worried about? Is there anywhere else I can download Git?
(Note, I am aware there are plenty of GUIs out there eg GitHub Desktop but I specifically want to use the command line).

Comment: Which OS are you using? In unix-like systems or Cygwin it should be available via package manager, or in Windows non-cygwin you can [go here](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)

Answer (score -1):

Where did you find the Sourceforge (avoid because of adware!) links? All the links from the official download page (https://git-scm.com/downloads) point to their own server. It's safe.

Comment: So I have been given the link you mention, I navigate through by clicking downloads for Mac then 'click here to download manually' since the download doesn't start automatically, the link takes me to Sourceforge.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't check the Mac links as you didn't specify the OS in the first place.